# CoreData many to many relationship insert and delete operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, many-to-many

I have a question about CoreData relationships.

I have this situation:

I have DOG and BONE entity.

- Each DOG can have more BONE.
- Each BONE can have more DOG.

So I need a many to many relationship.

how do I set the report delete in CoreData? what kind?

I think I need something as this:

- When I delete a BONE I do not have to remove the DOG;
- When I delete a DOG I do not have to remove the BONE if this is used from a DOG.
- When I delete a DOG I have to remove the BONEs if these are used only from this DOG.

Is this mechanism automatic for CoreData if I impose this relationship type?

About insert?

For example: I need to insert a DOG with some Bones: How do I check if the bone already exists? 
Every bone in my table has an ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is difficult to get a handle on your example as it doesn't make intuitive sense. That being said, ignoring the entity type, if you have an entity A and B with a mutual to-many relationship (many-to-many).

[Apple: Relationships and Fetched Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

(for the sake of brevity assume 'entity' = 'entity instance' below)

To Insert:

- You must insert both entity A and insert entity B. Core data will not
  automagically create entity B if you create entity A, just because they have a relationship
- If you wish to associate an existing entity B to a new entity A, then
  you must insert entity A then link entity A to entity B via the
  relationship. Just because you defined the relationship in the object model, doesn't mean the objects will be automagically related when you insert them. you need to explicitly do this

To Delete:

- Coredata will allow you to set the 'relationship delete rules'. This will govern what happens when you delete an object on one end of the relationship. You must set the rules on each end as you may choose to delete either entity A or entity B. Delete rules include: deny, nullify, cascade, no action. Check out Apple's doc on this to get you question above answered (it is clear).
- To apply your example to the delete rules:

When I delete a BONE I do not have to remove the DOG; (no action)
When I delete a DOG I do not have to remove the BONE if this is used from a DOG. (deny or nullify)
When I delete a DOG I have to remove the BONEs if these are used only from this DOG. (cascade)